# OpenGL Triangle rotation

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

I drew a triangle and i want to rotate it on X-Axis continuously. Below code is rotating it for couple of times.

```
//Paints the GL scene
void GLobj::paintGL(void)
{
   static int angle;
for (angle = 1; angle<=360; angle += 1)
{  
   glClear (GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
   glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
   glRotatef(angle, 1, 0 , 0);
   glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
   glColor3f (1.0, 0.0,1.0);
   glVertex2f(-0.45,0.0);
   glVertex2f(-0.65,0.5);
   glVertex2f(-0.25,0.5);
   glEnd();
   usleep(1000);
glFlush ();

}
```

If i change the above code as below, output is just busy in executing and not displaying anything.

```
//Paints the GL scene
void GLobj::paintGL(void)
{
   static int angle;
for (angle = 1; angle<=360; angle += 1)
{
   glClear (GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
   glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

   glRotatef(angle, 1, 0 , 0);

   glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
   glColor3f (1.0, 0.0,1.0);
   glVertex2f(-0.45,0.0);
   glVertex2f(-0.65,0.5);
   glVertex2f(-0.25,0.5);
   glEnd();
   usleep(1000);

if (angle == 360)
{angle = 1;}
}

glFlush ();

}
```

Is there any other better way of implementing continuous rotation?

Comment: It's not displaying anything because you are not flushing the command queue at any point. You really should not be using single-buffered rendering these days anyway, it usually does not work on most systems that use compositing window managers or hybrid integrated/discrete GPU switching.

Comment: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenGL_Programming/Modern_OpenGL_Introduction

Answer (score 0):

Most graphic APIs like OpenGL and DirectX write all changes into something called back buffer: The operations are only displayed once you have rendered your complete scene. If each rotation step or `glEnd()` rendered immediately, you would always see your scene building up each time. The result would be flickering which is not nice to see.

You can tell OpenGL when you have finished drawing your scene, so that everything can be displayed at once. You do this with `glFlush`.

In your second example, you conduct a rotation and another one and yet another one... at the very end you display your final scene once. The nice transition of your triangle through the rotation phases is not rendered.